# Last character of a string should be a letter or a number

Tags: php

I have these string:

```
$string = 'Tester,';
```

Finally I would like to get:

> 'Tester'

I tried like that:

```
$string = rtrim($string, array(',', '.'));
```

but second argument of rtrim() couldn't be an array.

How I can remove from end of a string everything what isn't letter or number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just check if the last character of the string isn't alphanumeric wtih [`ctype_alnum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php). If true I set the last character empty otherwise I leave it)

```
<?php

    $string = "Tester,";
    $string[strlen($string)-1] = (!ctype_alnum($string[strlen($string)-1])?"":$string[strlen($string)-1]);
    echo $string;

?>
```

output:

```
Tester
```

Comment: I'd personally store the value of `strlen($string)-1` in a variable to avoid repeating the function call and the subtraction 3 times.

Comment: @DJDavid98 yeah this is also possible or OP could use `substr($string, -1)`

Comment: This would only remove the last character.. OP asked for *everything that isn't letter or number*.  If the string happens to be `tester,@' it would fail.

Comment: @billynoah Depends on how you interpret *end of a string* which I took as last character and since OP accept it I think it is what he wants. And if not he would have made a bad example and an unclear question

Comment: Well I still think my answer is better :-) But yeah you're right

Answer (score 1):

Another solution are regular expressions.

This solves your task: `preg_replace('/(.*)[^a-zA-Z0-9]$/', '$1', 'Tester,');`

**Regex in action:**

[Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/r/kG5wJ3/2)

[Codeshare.io - PHP Sample](http://www.codeshare.io/FgSrp)

**Description**

The regular expression used for this task looks for a string that starts with any character `^(.*)` and does not end with a (alpha-)numeric character `[^a-zA-Z0-9]$`. The preg_replace replaces the match with the value of the so called backreference. A backreference is a reference to the value of a group. A group is everything between curved brackets.

**Links**

[Regex reference](http://regexhero.net/reference/)

Comment: Regular expressions should be taught in school :-) Nice one liner.

Comment: Thanks :-) Yeah that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_match()` to remove any non alpha-numeric characters from end of string like this:

```
preg_match('/(.+[a-zA-Z0-9])/',$string,$matches);
$string = $matches[0];
```

Comment: If more than the last character that is not (alpha-)numeric have to be removed this is a good way to go.